# Table numbering starts from negative numbers (Table -1, Table 0, Table 1,...)

Tags: tables, numbering

So the numbering of the tables is messed up, starting at -1. I cannot provide a minimal example because the minimal example I tried actually works correctly. I also can't post my entire thesis here. I am just looking for advice as to what could be causing this.

I am using `[H]` in my tables from package `float`. At first, I thought that was the problem but removing it didn't solve it either.

The figures and equations are numbered correctly.

I am using class `abntex2` and using the following packages: `mhchem`, `siunitx`, `float`, `cool`, `adjustbox` and `makecell`.

Comment: Sadly, the number of reliable psychics on this site is very small; in fact, the number may be zero. Unless you provide a few more pieces of information, beginning with the document class you employ and the names of the packages you load, the odds of anyone being able to guess correctly what’s afflicting your document are going to be poor.

Comment: I am sorry to be inappropriate. All I am thinking is which sort of information I should give. I am also wondering why this gives no results whatsoever on Google for this problem.

Comment: You can _always_ make an example. Start with a copy of your thesis, delete everything after the table -1, delete everything before the table that you can delete while still showing the error. Once it is small enough to post post it. If you delete something and the error goes, then you have found the problem yourself.

Comment: You are unlikely to find anything by google as no standard latex command ever decrements the table counter, so basically you have (something equivalent to) `\setcounter{table}{-1}` somewhere in your document. So the problem is specific to your document and without an example no one can help much.